# storeFreeze and ngrx8

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular8

I just mage an upgrade to ngrx/store version 8. I noticed that the ng update has removed all the occurrencies of storeFreeze. Is also removed it from the metaReducer.

So my question is - **why**?

Is there a problem using storeFreeze with ngrx 8?

before ngrx8:

```
import { ActionReducerMap, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';
import * as fromGroupMember from './group-member.reducer';
import * as fromDirectoryForm from './directory-filter-form.reducer';

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<IState>[] =
(localStorage && localStorage.getItem('production') === 'false') ? [storeFreeze] : [];
```

after:

```
import { ActionReducerMap, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromGroupMember from './group-member.reducer';
import * as fromDirectoryForm from './directory-filter-form.reducer';

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<IState>[] =
(localStorage && localStorage.getItem('production') === 'false') ? [] : [];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A migration was added on [8.0.0-rc.1](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800-rc1-2019-06-04) to remove the usage of `ngrx-store-freeze` as according to:

> The majority of our users are probably using ngrx-store-freeze to
>   guard against state mutations. We have built-in run-time checks in
>   version 8 to guard against those.

See the [github issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1896).

Answer (score 6):

This is part of the migration if you run `ng update @ngrx/store`.
It should also have added [runtime checks](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks) as a replacement because it's now part of ngrx:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Should these runtime checks be disabled in production like `ngrx-store-freeze`?